# Mobile toggle position changes on nav bar in WordPress, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am trying to make mobile toggle responsive with all screen sizes, but I found that they take different positions on nav bar as shown on the screenshots below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd1IX.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqJ4o.png

My site: https://softcroco.com/

How can I make both of them responsive on all smartphones?

My code:

```
<div class="primary-navigation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
<a href="#" id="pull" class="toggle-mobile-menu"><?php esc_html_e( '', 'schema-lite' ); ?>

<script> document.getElementById('pull').addEventListener('click', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); var openIcon = document.querySelector('.open-icon'); var closeIcon = document.querySelector('.close-icon'); openIcon.style.display = openIcon.style.display === 'none' ? 'inline' : 'none'; closeIcon.style.display = closeIcon.style.display === 'none' ? 'inline' : 'none'; }); </script>

<nav id="navigation" class="primary-navigation mobile-menu-wrapper" role="navigation">
<?php

@media (max-width: 768px)
.icons {
margin-top: -27px;
font-size: 22px;
color: #fff;
.open-icon, .close-icon {
display: inline;
stroke: none;
vertical-align: middle;
transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
margin-top: -22px;
margin-left: -352px;
}
a#pull {
background: none!important;
display: flex!important;
margin-top: -5px;
font-size: 18px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 865px)
a#pull {
display: block;
width: 100%;
background: #1d2933;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px 0;
text-indent: 2%;
text-align: left;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
position: relative;
}
```

CSS changes! but nothing seems working !